# How to get missing directories with path array?

Tags: objective-c

For exmaple, there is a NSArray contains many path:

```
/foo
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/faz/baz/
```

so the path `/foo/bar/faz` is missing, is there any way to get the missing path with a high performance.

Please don't suggest to recurs root directory because the path may not exist, there is only path array

Comment: Start at the bottom and call `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`. But if you tell what you really want to achieve you might get a better answer.

Comment: What do you mean with *get the missing path*?

Comment: @vadian, i want to create missing directory refer to the path, for example, there is no directory `faz`, then the path /foo/bar/faz/baz/ should be unreasonable

Comment: It sounds to me like you are trying to workaround some issue, which can be solved more elegant. Maybe describe your use case. Why you need the "missing path".

Answer (score 0):

Not nice, but working:

```
let paths = ["/foo", "/foo/bar", "/foo/bar/faz/baz"]

var lastPath = Array<String>()

for var path in paths {
    path.characters.removeFirst()
    var components = path.components(separatedBy: "/")
    if lastPath.count > 0 && components.count > lastPath.count + 1 {
        components.removeLast()
        print("missing: \("/")\(components.joined(separator: "/"))")
    }

    lastPath = components
}
```

Prints:

```
missing: /foo/bar/faz
```

Comment: when the path array is very complex， the result is incorrect

Comment: Post a complex example. My sample shows the idea, but does not handle all cases.